# I am looking for a short story about time travelling terrorists

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find a short story that I had read in 2008 or 2009. It had won some kind of award that year. It was about a psychologist who is sent to a secret detention facility where the government is holding a terrorist from the future. Any guesses?

Answer (score 8):

Robert Reed's "Truth" fits your bill.

[It was the runner-up for the Hugo Award for Best Novella in 2009](http://www.thehugoawards.org/hugo-history/2009-hugo-awards/) and was published in the October/November 2008 issue of Asimov's Science Fiction.

You can read the first part of it [here](http://www.asimovs.com/_issue_0810/truth.shtml), but the full story seems to only be available in the actual issue.  It was available in full for some time after the awards in 2009, but it seems to have been taken down from that location.

Comment: Using the link provided for the full story off of one of the websites, I learned that the Wayback Machine works on it: https://web.archive.org/web/20090414062819/http://www.asimovs.com/hugos_2009/Truth.shtml